# How to Separate values from json array using jquery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, jquery-mobile

This is my json

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "1",
      "Skylar Melovia"
    ],
    [
      "4",
      "Mathew Johnson"
    ]
  ]
}
```

`this is my code jquery Code`

```
for(i=0; i<= contacts.data.length; i++) {
    $.each(contacts.data[i], function( index, objValue ){
        alert("id "+objValue);
    });
}
```

i got the data in my `objValue` but i want to store separately in array of `id` and `name` it looks like this look at my code is bellow

```
var id=[];
var name = [];
for(i=0; i<= contacts.data.length; i++){
    $.each(contacts.data[i], function( index, objValue ) {
        id.push(objValue[index]); // This will be the value "1" from above JSON
        name.push(objValue[index]); // This will be the value "Skylar Melovia"   from above JSON
    });
}
```

How can i do this.

Comment: Its working as you want right? Define the problem better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $.each(contacts.data, function( index, objValue )
 {
    id.push(objValue[0]); // This will be the value "1" from above JSON
    name.push(objValue[1]); // This will be the value "Skylar Melovia"   from above JSON

 });
```

Edit, alternative usage :

```
 $.each(contacts.data, function()
 {
    id.push(this[0]); // This will be the value "1" from above JSON
    name.push(this[1]); // This will be the value "Skylar Melovia"   from above JSON
 });
```

The $.each will iterate over contacts.data which is :

```
[
    //index 1
    [
      "1",
      "Skylar Melovia"
    ],
    //index=2
    [
      "4",
      "Mathew Johnson"
    ]

]
```

The anomnymous function you give with signature function(index,Objvalue) will be applied on each element with `index` it's index in the contact.data array and `objValue` its value. For index=1 you will have :

```
objValue=[
          "1",
          "Skylar Melovia"
        ]
```

Then you can access objValue[0] and objValue[1].

EDIT (in response to Dutchie432 comment and answer ;) ):
Faster way to do it without jQuery, $.each is nicer to write and read but here you use plain old JS :

```
for(i=0; i<contacts.data.length; i++){
    ids.push(contacts.data[i][0];
    name.push(contacts.data[i][1];
}
```

Comment: Well, there you have it. 3 different answers all making the same point. This is probably the best answer since mine lazily uses `.length` in the for loop. Yours is more slick.

Comment: slick but when you don't especially need jQuery you should use for loop anyways but I guess OP needs to see how $.each works

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am not understanding fully, but I think you are looping through the data items, and then looping through the contained values as well. I think what you want is just to loop through the data items and pull values 0 and 1 respectively.

Also, I believe you want the `less than (<)` operator in your loop as opposed to the `less than or equal to (<=)`

```
for(i=0; i<contacts.data.length; i++){
    ids.push(contacts.data[i][0];
    name.push(contacts.data[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outer `for` loop.  `$.each` already iterates over the `data` array.  `data[i]` is not an array, so `$.each` cannot iterate over it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/4p5yh/

You could also use the `for` loop instead of `$.each`, but not both.